# How to make Android Guessing Game to restrict the number of guesses to 3 attempts after which a message will be displayed

Tags: java, android, if-statement, random, try-catch

I need to make the android guessing game I have so far to have a limit of 3 attempts after which the message like game over will be displayed, however I have no idea how to do it as I'm still new to programming so I would appreciate your help

Android Code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Task1Activity extends Activity {

private TextView tvPlayer;
private EditText eName;
private Button butSubmit;
private TextView nameOutput;
private TextView tvNumber;
private EditText eNumber;
private TextView numOutput;
private Button butGuess;
private Button butStart;
private String name_output;
private String number_output;
private TextView tvTries;
private TextView tvTries2;
public static int N;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.task1_layout);
    //Reference the input and output views on the interface
    tvPlayer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPlayer);
    eName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eName);
    butSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butSubmit);
    tvNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);
    eNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eNumber);
    butGuess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butGuess);
    butStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butStart);
    nameOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameOutput);
    numOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numOutput);
    tvTries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTries);
    tvTries2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTries2);
}


public void addClick1(View Button){
      name_output = eName.getText().toString(); //get the existing comments
      nameOutput.setText(name_output);//Display the new comments
    } public void addClick2(View Button){
Random r = new Random();
int Low = 0;
int High = 20;
N = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
}

public void addClick3(View Button){



      number_output = eNumber.getText().toString(); //get the existing comments

      try {
            int compareNum = Integer.parseInt(number_output);
             if(compareNum == N){
                  numOutput.setText(number_output + " Good Guess!");//Display the new comments
                  numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
              }else if(compareNum > N){
                  numOutput.setText(number_output + " is too HIGH!");//Display the new comments
                  numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
              }else if(compareNum < N){
                  numOutput.setText(number_output + " is too LOW!");//Display the new comments
                  numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
              }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a count on the clicks something like:

```
public void addClick2(View Button){
Random r = new Random();
int Low = 0;
int High = 20;
int count = 0;
N = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
}

public void addClick3(View Button){
      count++;
      number_output = eNumber.getText().toString(); //get the existing comments

      try {
            int compareNum = Integer.parseInt(number_output);
             if(compareNum == N){
                  numOutput.setText(number_output + " Good Guess!");//Display the new comments
                  numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
              }else if(compareNum > N){
                  numOutput.setText(number_output + " is too HIGH!");//Display the new comments
                  numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
              }else if(compareNum < N){
                  numOutput.setText(number_output + " is too LOW!");//Display the new comments
                  numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
              }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        if(count == 3){
            //set your game over message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is what I was looking for, however I had to create a public static int count; at the top of my code in order to make it work, anyway thanks for help :)

Comment: You don't need it static necessary, you need it just at the top of your code as a class variable!

Comment: now I see thank you :) any idea on how to amend the background colour depending on closeness of guess?

Comment: You are doing it, am i wrong? numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: Yes I mean something like if the guessed number is like 2 numbers closer to the one that was randomly generated the background would be lets say yellow, and then the rest stays as it is, do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Beda do you mean the whole activity background?

Comment: no I mean something like lets say if the random number generated by app is e.g. 10 and the number guessed would be e.g. 8 or 12 (two numbers closer to the generated one) the text background color will be numOutput.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); and if the number guessed would be further then it will stay as it is, I know it is confusing ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73013/discussion-between-fondesa-and-beda).